# Regular expression for matching css urls

Tags: css, regex, data-url

I have regular expression

```
/url\\(\\s*(?!data:)([^\\)\\s]+)\\s*\\)?/
```

It searches in css for lines like this

```
background-image: url(/path.to/img.png);
```

And ignores the lines

```
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64, PHN2ZyB4bWxucz) no-repeat;
```

It is used to find image paths and replace them.

But if Data url has quotes

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64, PHN2ZyB4bWxucz") no-repeat;
```

Regular expression matches it. I need to match usual image url and ignore Data url with single, double quotes or without them.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring that out. Did you have a question?

Comment: That is actually my question because I am not strong in regular expressions and will spend days to do that. Maybe someone do that faster then me.

Comment: Questions usually have a `?` in them... all you've done is treat this place as a "do my job for me" jobs board.

Comment: But others also asked such questions and I answered them if I knew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url\\(\\s*(?!["']?data:)([^)]+)\\)
```

In this regex, it will ignore anything like below(accepting optional space after `(`

```
url("data...
url(data:...
```

Which means it will only match the first example that you have given on the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but your expression does not match `background-image: url("/path/to/img.jpg");`.

Comment: Thanks your answer do exactly what I want.

Comment: Thanks. I have added checking for an eventual space before `data` or `"data`or `'data`:  url\\(\\s*(?!`\\s*["']?data:)([^)]+)\\)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use pattern with `("|')?`:

```
/url\\(("|')?\\s*([^(:;,]+)\\s*("|')?\\);?/
```

`("|')?` allow you also to match single or double quotes

Comment: Sorry I tried `/url\\((\"|')?\\s*(?!data:)([^\\)\\s]+)\\s*(\"|')?\\)?/` but it still matches data url with both quotes(.

Comment: Now its not matching string with usual url. I think `("|')?` should be used somewhere inside `(?!data:)`.

Comment: Using `:;,` instead of `data` is cool idea. But as a result it is not selecting sub strings as I expected. The another answer suits me perfect. I like your answer but cannot accept it.